# ASP.NET Web Service return arraylist of different object types

Tags: asp.net, arrays, list, service, web

I got a problem when I tried ASP.NET WebService to return arraylist of several object types.
Suppose I have a Book object and a Table object.
I added Book and Table objects to an ArrayList.
After that I return that arraylist in webservice. It does not allow me to do.
How can I make it be able to return several object types?

Comment: What does it mean it does not allow you? can you show your web method signature? is this XML web services not WCF right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not define a complex object (DTO in this examle) that contains the other objects and return the populated DTO in you webmethod:

```
[OperationContract]
Dto GetBooksAndTables();


[DataContract]
public class Dto
{
    [DataMember]
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Table[] Tables { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Book 
{
   [DataMember]
   public string BookName {get; set; }
   //etc...
}

[DataContract]
public class Table 
{
   [DataMember]
   public string TableName {get; set; }
   //etc...
}
```

Have you looked at http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP -  it makes building .NET services much easier. It's on NuGet.